# does boost::circular_buffer acknowledge an automatic pop operation

Tags: c++, boost

Is it mandatory to store `std::shared_ptr`'s  in `boost::circular_buffer` ? If I've a `boost::circular_buffer<T*>` does the circular queue `delete`s the element that is automatically popped by itself after n+1th insertion ?

If not then how would I delete the popped elements and manage memory leaks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's not *mandatory* to store `shared_ptr`s, you can store lots of different types, e.g. something as simple as `int`

If you store pointers the container doesn't know they point to objects on the heap, so it doesn't delete them when overwriting existing elements with new elements, it can't know that it would be safe to delete a pointer. The pointer is just overwritten with a new value. If that was the last pointer to an object on the heap you have a memory leak. This is pretty clearly [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#caveats) less than a quarter of the way down the page. Maybe you should read the documentation.

If you store pointers to heap objects and you have no other way to manage them then yes, storing `shared_ptr<T>` is sensible (but not mandatory).

Comment: @MooingDuck: As of boost 1.50, `boost::circular_buffer` has not been updated to support move-only objects.